# Is it possible to get ip address of a router thru mac id?

Tags: mac, router, ip, isp

Is it possible to get ip address of a router thru its mac id (router) ? also
I am connected in the same network (ISP)

Comment: Are you on the same network segment?   Since you're mentioning an ISP, I'm guess not.  So, the answer is no.

Comment: I'm using the same ISP but don't know the segment of the target router ip

Comment: Any respectable ISP is going to keep its customers segmented so that they are not on the same segment, and therefore MAC address is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to correlate the MAC address with IP using ARP. To perform a lookup, bring up command prompt and type in:

```
arp -a
```

If your MAC address is not listed here, ping your broadcast IP in your network to populate the arp table on your machine and then check again with **arp -a**.